# ASP.NET - can't reach page iis server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Currently I have problem with running my app on iis server.
I have developed my app using .NET 8.0 (MVC app).Then I have published it to folder.

On my server I have installed .NET 8.0, ASP.NET hosting bundle, .NET SDK 8.0

I have uploaded my folder to server, set up virtual path and then added app
[image]
[image]
For applicationpool set up No manged code
[image]
When I run page it shows can't reach page

What should I check to resolve it?

Comment: tracert from a command prompt will show if there is something we you don't even reach server. Event Viewer on the server will tell you if something is wrong. Also note you may have to start app pool because it has been turned off automatically after a few failures.